# Question about mixed strategy game theory

Tags: game-theory

I have no idea how the game is solved. Especially how do you begin with writing the norm form of the game. Appreciate your help!
[image]

I assume the probability p of defense playing Left
For the opponent's payoff if playing left:
$$p * (-1) + (1-p) * (-5)$$
For the oppoent's payoff if playing right:
$$p * (-5) + (1-p) *(-3.5)$$

Equating both, $p=0.27$ and $(1-p)=0.72.$
But there is no matching answer.

Comment: Nope. You should show your work on solving the problem, otherwise the question will be closed

Comment: Suggestion: the line towards the end *"If it makes 5 yards or more it wins, if not it loses"* should help in making the game simple. Forget about yards, and write the game in two players, with two possible actions, and two possible outcomes: win/lose. You can simply define payoff as 1/0 for this.

Comment: how then, would you deal with 0.7 probability?

Comment: a payoff of 0.7 instead of 1

Comment: so the opponent payoff is 0.3 right~~ looks like a "one-sum" game haha

Comment: yes. perhaps now you can see that solution is going to be $p=1/1.3$.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the mistake of looking at the problem, seeing some numbers, and thinking those are the payoffs. It's a common mistake for novices in game theory to treat the numerical gain as being the same as utility. The payoff for a result in this game is not the number of yards gained, but the probability of a win. That is, for each square in the payoff matrix, the entry is the probability of winning.

Also, when you post an image, you're supposed to transcribe it.

Comment: Thanks! I realize that. Because all problems I've seen are related to numbers as payoff. Thanks for the hint